# Pandas: Check whether the particular day is in index at regular interval and if not mark the one before entry as something?

Tags: python, pandas

I am still very new to pandas and just figured out I have made a mistake in the process I was following earlier.

```
 df_date
         Date        day
0  2016-05-26   Thursday
1  2016-05-27     Friday
2  2016-05-30     Monday
3  2016-05-31    Tuesday
4  2016-06-01  Wednesday
5  2016-06-02   Thursday
6  2016-06-03     Friday
7  2016-06-06     Monday
8  2016-06-07    Tuesday
9  2016-06-08  Wednesday
10 2016-06-09   Thursday
11 2016-06-10     Friday
12 2016-06-13     Monday
13 2016-06-14    Tuesday
14 2016-06-15  Wednesday
15 2016-06-16   Thursday
16 2016-06-17     Friday
17 2016-06-20     Monday
18 2016-06-21    Tuesday
19 2016-06-22  Wednesday
20 2016-06-24     Friday
21 2016-06-27     Monday
22 2016-06-28    Tuesday
23 2016-06-29  Wednesday
```

There are about 600+ rows.

What I want to do

Make a column `'Exit'` where if `thursday` is not in the week the Wednesday becomes E and if wednesday is not there then Tuesday.

I tried a for loop and I just can't seem to get this right.

Expected Output:

```
 df_date
         Date        day  Exit
0  2016-05-26   Thursday  E
1  2016-05-27     Friday  
2  2016-05-30     Monday
3  2016-05-31    Tuesday
4  2016-06-01  Wednesday
5  2016-06-02   Thursday  E
6  2016-06-03     Friday
7  2016-06-06     Monday
8  2016-06-07    Tuesday
9  2016-06-08  Wednesday
10 2016-06-09   Thursday  E
11 2016-06-10     Friday
12 2016-06-13     Monday
13 2016-06-14    Tuesday
14 2016-06-15  Wednesday
15 2016-06-16   Thursday  E
16 2016-06-17     Friday
17 2016-06-20     Monday
18 2016-06-21    Tuesday
19 2016-06-22  Wednesday  E
20 2016-06-24     Friday
21 2016-06-27     Monday
22 2016-06-28    Tuesday
23 2016-06-29  Wednesday  E
```

I added this in comments but should be here as well:

If Thursday is not present then the record just before it.

So if Wednesday is also not present in the week, then Tuesday

If Tuesday is also not then Monday, if monday is not then Friday. Saturday and Sunday will never have a record.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: Sorry About that just did.

Comment: How about when tuesday is not present? Should Monday be set as `E`?

Comment: @yatu yes if Thursday is not present the record just before it. So if Wednesday is also not present in the week, then Tuesday if Tuesday is also not then Monday, if monday is not then Friday. Saturday and Sunday will never have a record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
ix = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='W')).Date
       .apply(lambda x: (x.dt.dayofweek <= 3)[::-1].idxmax()).values
df.loc[ix,'Exit'] = 'E'
df.fillna('')

      Date        day     Exit
0  2016-05-26   Thursday    E
1  2016-05-27     Friday     
2  2016-05-30     Monday     
3  2016-05-31    Tuesday     
4  2016-06-01  Wednesday     
5  2016-06-02   Thursday    E
6  2016-06-03     Friday     
7  2016-06-06     Monday     
8  2016-06-07    Tuesday     
9  2016-06-08  Wednesday     
10 2016-06-09   Thursday    E
11 2016-06-10     Friday     
12 2016-06-13     Monday     
13 2016-06-14    Tuesday     
14 2016-06-15  Wednesday     
15 2016-06-16   Thursday    E
16 2016-06-17     Friday     
17 2016-06-20     Monday     
18 2016-06-21    Tuesday     
19 2016-06-22  Wednesday     
20 2016-06-23   Thursday    E
21 2016-06-24     Friday     
22 2016-06-27     Monday     
23 2016-06-28    Tuesday     
24 2016-06-29  Wednesday    E
```

Comment: Technically, `< 3` will also capture Monday (not specified by OP). But otherwise a great solution.

Comment: Hi @yatu thanks for the solution but it seems that even though thursday is in the week for example at 2016-06-23 is a thursday but the solution is giving 'E' ealier in the same week at 2016-06-2016. I wanted to put 'E'  before Thursday only if Thursday doesn't exist in the week and the record just before the expected thursday i.e. 2016-06-22 in the expample.

Comment: My bad, I was using `<3` instead of `<=3`:). Should work now

Comment: I am getting this error: >Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
in _get_setitem_indexer
    return self._convert_tuple(key, is_setter=True)
in _convert_tuple
    idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i, is_setter=is_setter)
  File "/media/sid1/sid/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: '[-1] not in index'

Comment: Forgot to change something in the second line, should work now @sid

Comment: @yatu thanks! Works now. Saved me from hours of trying out lists and then trying to figure how it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dt.week` and `dt.weekday` properties of your `datetime` series. Then use `groupby` + `max` for your required logic. This is likely to be more efficient than sequential equality checks.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# add week and weekday series
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.week
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday.where(df['Date'].dt.weekday.isin([1, 2, 3]))

df['Exit'] = np.where(df['Weekday'] == df.groupby('Week')['Weekday'].transform('max'),
                      'E', '')
```

**Result**

I have left the helper columns so the way the solution works is clear. These can easily be removed.

```
print(df)

         Date        day  Week  Weekday Exit
0  2016-05-26   Thursday    21      3.0    E
1  2016-05-27     Friday    21      NaN     
2  2016-05-30     Monday    22      NaN     
3  2016-05-31    Tuesday    22      1.0     
4  2016-06-01  Wednesday    22      2.0     
5  2016-06-02   Thursday    22      3.0    E
6  2016-06-03     Friday    22      NaN     
7  2016-06-06     Monday    23      NaN     
8  2016-06-07    Tuesday    23      1.0     
9  2016-06-08  Wednesday    23      2.0     
10 2016-06-09   Thursday    23      3.0    E
11 2016-06-10     Friday    23      NaN     
12 2016-06-13     Monday    24      NaN     
13 2016-06-14    Tuesday    24      1.0     
14 2016-06-15  Wednesday    24      2.0     
15 2016-06-16   Thursday    24      3.0    E
16 2016-06-17     Friday    24      NaN     
17 2016-06-20     Monday    25      NaN     
18 2016-06-21    Tuesday    25      1.0     
19 2016-06-22  Wednesday    25      2.0    E
20 2016-06-24     Friday    25      NaN     
21 2016-06-27     Monday    26      NaN     
22 2016-06-28    Tuesday    26      1.0     
23 2016-06-29  Wednesday    26      2.0    E
```

Comment: thanks for the helper column. I think this works perfectly. I am trying to learn through the code.

Comment: Ah..doesn't work on weeks where only 1 and 2 and in the helper columns at my end.

Comment: @Sid, Can't see why it *wouldn't* work. Would need some example data to demonstrate.

Comment: Nice solution also @jpp. However there is an aspect neither of our solutions are contemplating which makes it a little trickier, which is `if monday is not then Friday`

Comment: @yatu, OK, I see that's in a comment. I'd rather not answer comments.. really, the question should be updated. Otherwise we'll end up with a disjointed Q&A.

Comment: @jpp shall I upload the file?

Comment: @Sid, No, please don't.

Comment: @jpp Yes agreed it should have been specified in the question, otherwise logical solution is to group by week

Comment: @yatu, It's easy enough to shift Monday to the *next* week... `df.loc[df['Weekday'].eq(0), 'Week'] += 1`. Then group by week.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to try and learn more about `groupby` and `lambda`